# How to display rows of the database one after the another using a button using php?

Tags: php

I am having a database with values like

- mango
- appple
- oranges

and now I want to display these values into a html table individually. Like the first row is only mango and then I click next button then apple and then next button then oranges.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a php array like `$array(0=>"mango",1=>"apple",2=>"oranges")`.

```
<table >
<tr>
<td id="myTable">
<?php echo $array[0]; ?>
</td>
</tr>
<script>var iterator = 0;</script>
<input type="button" value="next" onclick="nextVal(iterator)"/>

function nextVal(nextVal){
nextVal++;
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "<?php echo $array["+nextVal+"]; ?>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am having the values in the database and am unable to display them row by row...following is the code for the perusal                                  mysql_connect("localhost","mvsr","mvsr");
// Check connection
mysql_select_db("mvsr");
$resul = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name");
$i=0;
$row = mysql_fetch_array($resul);
  do
  {
    foreach $row as $key => $value
  echo "<td>" . $value[i] . "</td>";
  $i++;
  }while($i<=$row); the above code is not working ....